# Multiple underscores at the end using REGEX?

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a REGEX checker that is supposed to return true with the following conditions:

It has to begin with either an underscore '_'  or a dot '.'

It has to be immediately followed by one or more occurrences of digits numbered 0-9

It can then have letters, both uppercase or lowercase, 0 or more in number

It can then end with an optional '_'

```
System.out.println(str.matches("^(_|\\.)[0-9]+[a-zA-z]*(_?)$"));
```

The above code works for every case except of cases where the string ends with several underscores, which should return a false, but strangely returns true. I tried several things but unfortunately haven't been able to make it work.

> _08__ for example is returning true when it should be false.

Comment: `[A-z]` is the culprit. Use `.matches("[_.][0-9]+\\p{L}*_?")`. It will also support all Unicode letters. Or replace `\\p{L}` with `[a-zA-Z]` to only support ASCII letters.

Comment: You are completely right it was just a Typo with the "z" instead of "Z"